# How to properly pass reCaptcha system using Protractor

Tags: protractor, recaptcha

In order to validate an application containing a reCaptcha, I've written a simple function like this:

```
it('And I validate the captcha.', function () {

        registration.clickOnCaptcha();

});
```

clickOnCaptcha() looks like this:

```
this.clickOnCaptcha = function() {

    // Switch to the iFrame where the captcha is
    browser.driver.switchTo().frame(0);

    // Disable waitForAngular since the iFrame is not in Angular
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

    browser.element(by.id('recaptcha-anchor')).click();

    // Dirty way to allow Captcha animation to finish
    browser.sleep('3000');

    // Enable waitForAngular before going back to the main frame
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);

    // Switch back to the main frame
    browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
};
```

I wanted to know if some of you have found a better way to do this?

Furthermore, I'm wondering if the best way to disable the waitForAngular function is to do it **before** or **after** switching into the iFrame.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

This is the code I use for reCaptcha

```
let recaptcha = $(iframeString); //String is previously built depending on page I am on
await browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(recaptcha),browser.params.longWait);
await util.scrollTo(recaptcha); //Sometime reCaptcha is out of view. This function brings it into view
let elem = await browser.driver.findElement(by.css(iframeString));
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
await browser.switchTo().frame(elem);
await $('#recaptcha-anchor').click();
await browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
await browser.sleep(1500); // Waiting for the reCAPTCHA to load
```

This is very similar to the way you do it. I would advise switching to the specific reCaptcha frame instead of frame(0) but that is the biggest improvement I can see.

Answer (score -1):

you can replace `browser.sleep('3000');` by

```
await browser.wait(
  async () => (await element(by.css("#recaptcha-accessible-status")).getAttribute("textContent")) === "You are verified"
);
```

`recaptcha-accessible-status` is a hidden field, that changes the text when captcha is verified.